# Write file in linux with java isn't working

Tags: java, linux

a java code i've been  working in Windows worked perfectly, but when i tried to run it in linux didn't work (i.e it didn't create the file and therefore didn't write)...these are the functions i'm using:

```
    BufferedWriter writer =null;//
    String directory= "folder/";
    java.io.File directory1 = new File(directory+"resultado");
    String directory2;
    directory1.mkdirs();

    directory2=directory+"resultado/";
    try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(directory2+"resultado.txt"), "utf-8"));
    writer.write("something");  
    writer.newLine();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERRORR!!!!");
        ex.printStackTrace() ;
        // report
    } finally {
        try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {//ignore}
        }
    }
```

Even thoug i have the catch IOException  to write "Error" it gives me the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at memoria.bosques.imprimirenarchivos(bosques.java:17281)
    at memoria.bosques.main2(bosques.java:18096)
    at memoria.bosques.main(bosques.java:18139)
```

The folder of the directory is created, but it seems the functions don't create a file to write on it...what can i do?

Comment: Does the user running the Java process have adequate privileges to create files in the target folder, in the Linux host OS?

Comment: Can you give us a complete [mcve] including a main method?

Comment: @Peter L., sorry i mixed the idiom

Comment: try closing BufferedReader and File.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: @mastah , i close the writer.close()   is there anything else to close?

Comment: @durron597, now i put the code  corrected to run, if i chage the "/" for " \\" a path in windows works perfectly

Comment: @Emaneitron That wouldn't cure a null pointer exception. In fact it wouldn't change anything. They are equivalent in Java. There is never a need to use backslashes in Java file names.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `writer` is null in your `finally` block, because you got a prior exception, which you didn't tell us about. Either test it for null before closing, or use try-with-resources.

And when you get an exception, **don't** just print out `"ERROR!!!!"`. It's useless. Print the exception.

And when you call a method like `mkdirs()` that returns a result, don't ignore it.